# How to check if an int is within +/- some percentage

Tags: c

I'm writing this function that takes in 2 numbers ref and data and checks if data is within 5% of ref.

Example: if ref is 100 and data is 102, it returns 1.

```
int within_5_percent(int ref, int data)
{
int result = 0;
int lower_bound = (ref - 0.05 * ref);
int upper_bound = (ref + 0.05 * ref);

//  printf("Upper: %d\n",upper_bound);
//  printf("Lower: %d\n", lower_bound);
if(data >= lower_bound && data <= upper_bound)
{
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    result = 0;
}

return result;
}
```

The problem I'm having is at lower_bound. When I pass 100 as ref, the upper_bound is 105 but for some reason lower_bound is 94 when it should really be 95.

Comment: a `double` is getting rounded off as `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Comment: I might have been wrong about rounding: http://ideone.com/vPmQDQ

Comment: I actually tested this code and you seem to give different observations to common compilers output. What compiler are you using? Are these your exact results? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e54036f84b9e4cc

Comment: @typ1232 I'm using code blocks

Answer (score 2):

To convert this into integer arithmetic, we have `ref - 0.05 * ref` = `0.95 * ref` = 19/20 * `ref`, and similarly `ref + 0.05 * ref` = 21/20 * `ref`.

So we want to check whether 19/20 * `ref` ≤ `data` ≤ 21/20 * `ref`, or in other words whether `19 * ref <= 20 * data && 20 * data <= 21 * ref`. The code then becomes

```
int within_5_percent(int ref, int data)
{
int result = 0;

//  printf("Upper: %d\n",upper_bound);
//  printf("Lower: %d\n", lower_bound);
if(20 * data >= 19 * ref && 20 * data <= 21 * ref)
{
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    result = 0;
}

return result;
}
```

Note that any problems with floating-point arithmetic are gone. However, you could have problems with integer overflow if `ref` and `data` are too big (i.e. positive) or too small (i.e. negative).

Comment: To avoid range issues, likely `20LL * data >= 19LL * ref && 20LL * data <= 21LL * ref` will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

`lower_bound` takes on the value of 94 due to `0.05` not being exactly representable as a `double` and conversion back to `int` truncates the fraction.

```
int lower_bound = (int) 100 - (double) 0.05 * (int) 100 -->   
int lower_bound = 100 - 0.05000000000000000277... * 100 -->  
int lower_bound = 94.999....999... -->  
int lower_bound = 94;
```

A simple alternative using only integer math.

```
int within5(int ref, int data) {
  int lo = ref - ref/20;
  int hi = ref + ref/20;
  return (lo <= data && data <= hi);
}
```

As the above and various other answers fail with a negative `ref` or with large values,  following is a more secure method that I believe works for all `ref,data`.

```
int within5secure(int ref, int data) {
  int ref20 = abs(ref / 20);
  int lo = ref > INT_MIN + ref20 ? ref - ref20 : INT_MIN;
  int hi = ref < INT_MAX - ref20 ? ref + ref20 : INT_MAX;
  return (lo <= data && data <= hi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.05 * ref` triggers C's type promotion rules and evaluates to a `double`.

`ref - 0.05 * ref` then does the same thing, so the output of `(ref - 0.05 * ref)` is a `double`.

The effect of `int lower_bound = (ref - 0.05 * ref);` is then to assign a `double` to an `int`, which is performed by truncation. Which, for a positive floating point number, means rounding down.

Therefore all you're suffering from is rounding error. You could use `round(ref - 0.05 * ref)` to get the nearest integer rather than the one below it, or you could perform the whole calculation in integers, e.g. `lower_bound = (ref * 95) / 100;`

Comment: @Ben Well in ideone it works, but I realized rounding *could* actually be the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy I used (lower_bound = (ref * 95) / 100;) and seems to working fine, but I also compiled my original code using a different compiler and it gave correct output, must be something with code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
0.05 * ref
```

Will convert the result to double. It cannot be directly represended as a floating point number so the actual result is something like `5.000000001`.

```
100 - 5.000001 = 94.99999999
```

Which is then truncated to 94.

It depends how you want to solve this, but you could for example multiply by 5 and then divide by 100 to get 5%. But here you still have to define how to round the result after the division.

Comment: `5.0` can be exactly expressed as a floating point number: 0[.]101 in the mantissa, a value of 3 for the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `int lower_bound` and `int upper_bound` to `float lower_bound` and `float upper_bound` in your code because you might end up with decimal answers when you calculate `lower_bound = (ref - 0.05 * ref) and upper_bound = (ref + 0.05 *ref)`. For example when `ref=90` your `upper_bound` will be `94.5` and `lower_bound` will be `85.5`.

```
int within_5_percent(int ref, int data)
{
   int result = 0;
   float lower_bound = (ref - 0.05 * ref);
   float upper_bound = (ref + 0.05 * ref);

   // printf("Upper: %f\n",upper_bound);
   // printf("Lower: %f\n", lower_bound);
 if(data >= lower_bound && data <= upper_bound)
 {
    result = 1;
 }
 else
 {
  result = 0;
 }

 return result;
}
```